# Update an array with new objects

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have an object which gets updated when ever some data change occurs, i need to store the previous and updating data into an array and retrieve it when required

```
/* currently i could get 1 data i need multiple data stored to a storage as array*/
    get(){
        this.storage.get('uploaded').then((data) => {
            console.log("get data", JSON.parse(data));        
        });
    }

    set(){
        var obj = { upload: true,
                    file: file.audio //this will hold an object which vary when required
                  }

        this.storage.set('uploaded', JSON.stringify( obj ));
    }
```

Comment: Is file an array of a object ? i guess you need to  make any array of files and do a push if you need to have multiple values

Comment: yes file is an object could u create me a sample

Comment: you got a simple by @rahul hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **push()** method of array to update the array with new data.

```
var obj = new Array();
obj.push();// use this whenever you have new data
```

and use this to access the values

```
for (var i in obj) {
   //access values using obj[i]
}
```